# How to add a label to traces created by the AddOutgoingGoogleTraceHandler extension method?

Tags: c#, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-trace

I am using `Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore` v4.3.0.

I use `AddOutgoingGoogleTraceHandler` to trace every outgoing HTTP request of a given HTTP client and I want to add a custom label to every trace created by this method.

From what I understood, it is more precisely the underlying span of a trace that carries a label.

I read the most up-to-date [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Diagnostics.AspNetCore/4.3.0/index.html#using-tracing-with-other-than-googles-own-trace-header) but still didn't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I just learnt from the official Google team that this feature is simply not available and that they are in the process of making it real.

To have updates on this, follow this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/7430).